# Get newrelic dashboard char link dynamically using python

Tags: python, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I am trying to send new relic dashboard report automatically to slack. How can I get dashboard chartlink automatically using python in order to send report

[image]

Comment: See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5vBGV2Yy_0